# Is splitting a class in two different class a good idea?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

For a project I need to create report from Excel files.

I have a big design question that I can't solve myself and I haven't found a solution online.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Read the content of an Excel file
2. With that content initialize a new Report class
3. Profit!

The problem is that the first time I wrote that, I put everything inside my Report class (by everything I mean reading the file, formatting the fields, etc.) and I ended up with a big class.

I wasn't satisfied with that, so I tried to do something better and created a ReportReader class that contains all my reading file stuff and also getters to init a Report class. It is a good idea or should I stick to one class?

Also, could it be a good idea to create a createReport method inside ReportHeader instead of making public getters available?

```
public class ReportReader {
    private final File file;
    private final Sheet sheet;

    public ReportReader(File file) throws InvalidFormatException
        , IOException {
     
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFields() {

    }

    private String formatField(String input) {

    }

    public String getName() {
    
    }

    public Cell[][] getContent() {

    }

    public String getType() throws IOException {

    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Report {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private ArrayList<String> fields;
    private Cell[][] content;
    
    public Report(String name, String type, ArrayList<String> fields, 
        Cell[][] content) throws IOException {
    
    }
    
    public void saveFieldsModel() throws IOException {
       
    }
    
    public String getFieldsAsCsv() {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Using only one class is a bad idea. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle

Comment: @yuri777 Thanks for the response and the resource !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, creating a class per responisibility is good practice. It is one of principle of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). There is a great post about [clarifying of  single responsibility](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/clarify-the-single-responsibility-principle).

> could it be a good idea to create a createReport method inside ReportHeader instead of making public getters available?

It looks like `CreateReport` is not related to `ReportHeader`.  Class `Report` would be more appropriate place for `CreateReport()` method. In addition, if you will place the method `CreateReport()` in `Report` class, then you can call it like `Create`, not `CreateReport`:

```
public class Report {
    public void Create(){}
}
```

and then in user class it would look like this:

```
Report report = new Report();
report.Create(); // not "CreateReport()" :)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a small typo in my question. It is `ReportReader` not `ReportHeader` ...

So now since my `ReportReader` class contains everything I need to initialize a `Report` class it is appropriate to juste have a `.Create()` method in `ReportReader` instead of doind `new Report(reportReader.getX(); reportReader.getY(); ...)` ?

Comment: In my view, it depends on goal of the method? If "Create()" method creates Excel file, then it is fine to have `Create()` method. If class `Report` requires some parameters for constructor, then it is okay to instantiate like this `new Report(reportReader.getX(); reportReader.getY(); ...)`

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for giving me some of your time :)

Comment: @olsa you are welcome. I am glad that it helped to you. :)